# Llenar DataGriedView con Procedimiento almacenado que tiene 1 parametro, VB.Net y SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb

Tengo ya un procedimiento almacenado, que únicamente consta de 1 parametro, con eso no hay problema, la cosa es que hice el siguiente diseño en VB.Net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual en el **TextBox1** quiero ingresar el parámetro, y al darle al botón **Generar** el cual se llama **Button1** , me muestre el resultado del Procedimiento almacenado en el **DataGriedView1**, el procedimiento almacenado se llama **SP_InformacionCuentas** y el parámetro **@MesReportar**

He hecho la conexion a la BD entrando en la configuracion de MyProject

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego he puesto las credenciales y testeado la conexion y todo bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me ayuda porfavor soy algo nuevo en VB.Net

Comment: Usas Entity Framework o ADO a pelo para conectar con la base de datos?

Comment: Pues para hacer la conexión a la base de datos me fui en el apartado de MYPROJECT y desde configuración realice la conexión, edite la pregunta y agregue como lo hice

Comment: A ver, dale dobleclick al boton 'Generar' , eso te creara automaticamente un metodo en el codigo del back donde tienes que meter toda la magia, te paso un enlace con lo  que tienes que hacer: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 si te pierdes, edita con el codigo que hayas logrado juntar y te echaremos una mano